# Search invisible characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

There are some columns in my mysql table which contain values such as "Sbeed Pharmaceuticals åÊ" . Two questions:

1. How do I prevent getting these characters from getting into the table in the first place ?
2. How do I find rows containing these characters ?

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `drugs` (
  `drug-id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `th-class` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `division` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand-name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pack` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rx-type` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pack-form` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `available-in` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mrp` double DEFAULT '-1',
  `mrp-per-unit` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `schemes` text,
  `drug-status` varchar(64) DEFAULT 'new',
  `created-by` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created-at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `approved-at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved-by` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dosage` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer-id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`drug-id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: show your `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table` output? is your table utf8?

Comment: first, I would suggest to convert table into utf8 `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Comment: 1. Determine which characters you want to allow in your data and in the application you stop any entries that have any other characters in it. Furthermore, review your character encoding settings because it is possible that you have a character set conversion issue. 2. Determine which characters you want to allow in your data. Search for any field value that has other characters in it.

Comment: This looks like the classic case of inserting UTF-8 data into a Latin1 table. Make everything UTF-8 if you can.

Comment: Will converting table to UTF-8 get rid of these characters ?